# Why does a fieldset exceed the height of its container when the height is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css

See my code in action at: http://losthobbit.net/temp/radiogroup.html

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Radio Group Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Radiogroup" style="position: absolute; top: 9px; left: 12px; width: 234px; height: 177px; background-color:Aqua">
        <fieldset style="height: 100%">
            <legend>Radiogroup</legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the fieldset exceed the height of the div?

Thanks in advance

Comment: browsers handle margins and padding differently; look into `"reset.css"`

Comment: thank you for the hint, pixelbobby

Comment: I hope you find your way, Hobbit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers add some padding to fieldsets by default. Since it usually goes by the original W3C box model, the padding adds to the height rather than being part of it, hence what you see. You can easily remove that by setting zero padding on your fieldset.

You also have to take into account the height of the legend that's sticking out of the top of the fieldset. That is a bit more difficult to negate however; you may need to play around with its position styles, margins and so on to keep it in place but not let it affect your fieldset.

Comment: You're far too fast at answering. Thanks for the explanation about padding getting added to the height rather than being part of the fieldset. Didn't know about that, never noticed it in fact.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the browser's stylesheet. For example, in Chrome, some padding gets added:

```
    fieldset {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-start: 2px;
-webkit-margin-end: 2px;
-webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
-webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
-webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
-webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
```

Try using a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or simply set `padding: 0` on your fieldset.